# Finding general solution of a third-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cubics

I am given the equation:

$$y''' - 7y'' + 16y' + 10y = 0$$

where a root of the characteristic equation is $\lambda= -1$.

I gathered from this that $y=e^{-x}$ is a solution of the third order ODE.

I am asked to find the general solution of this ODE, so, I am trying to find another solution/s to the ODE, however, I am asked to find this solution without technology.

How can I solve the above cubic without a calculator? From the wording of the question, it sounds like I should use $y = e^{-x}$, but I am not sure how that can assist me.

I plugged the corresponding values in the ODE my calculator out of curiosity, and found that $\lambda = -3 + I$ and $\lambda = -3 - I$ are solutions to the characteristic equation..

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, polynomial division by the linear factor $λ+1$ reduces the cubic to a quadratic polynomial, where you can then complete the square or compute the roots otherwise. Now translate these roots into basis solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume the your equation is actually

$$ y''' \color{red}{+}7y'' + 16y' + 10y = 0 $$

Since $\lambda=-1$ does not solve the one you wrote.

Have you tried solving the characteristic polynomial first? Knowing one of the roots, it can be factored to

$$ (\lambda + 1)(\lambda^2 + 6\lambda + 10) = 0 $$